# How to use chain rule to find the gradient of vector function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential, chain-rule

Im reading [Matrix Differential Calculus](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07PS6Y6W6) by Magnus and I am having some difficulty understanding the chain rule. My goal is to write out the matrix form of an arbitrary machine learning model, and then use differentials to find the gradient w.r.t weights, but I am having trouble understanding the connection between differentials/gradients and how to move between them.

Let $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ be some matrix, $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ a column vector, and $g:\mathbb{R}^{m} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m}$ some differentiable function. Then define the following function.

$$f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m} \ \ \text{given by} \ \ f(x) = g(A^Tx) $$

Here is my attempt at finding the differtial of $f$.

1. $\  \textbf{d}f = \textbf{d}g(A^T x)$
2. $\ \ \ \ \ \ = \big[\textbf{D}g(y) \big]\textbf{d} \big(A^Tx \big)$
3. $\ \ \ \ \ \ = \big[\textbf{D}g(y) \big]\bigg((\textbf{d}A)^Tx + A^T(\textbf{d}x) \bigg)$

Where $\big[\textbf{D}g(y) \big]$ is the jacobian of $g$ at the point $y = A^Tx$. I think (3) is correct, but now trying to move to gradients I get lost. My understanding is that to find gradients I manipulate (3) to look like

4. $ \ \textbf{d} f = (J) \textbf{d}x $
5. $ \ \textbf{d} f = (K) \textbf{d}A $

Then $J$ would be $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $K$ would be $\frac{\partial f}{\partial A}$ (i think). How can I do this? If I try to find $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ I am tempted to treat $A$ as a constant in (3) so that $(\textbf{d}A)^T = 0$, and then get

$$\textbf{d} f = \big[\textbf{D}g(y) \big]A^T(\textbf{d}x) $$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} =  \big[\textbf{D}g(y) \big]A^T $$
$$\Rightarrow \nabla_x f = A  \big[\textbf{D}g(y) \big]^T$$

These dimensions don't seem right to me. If I consider $x$ to be a parameter of a loss function $f$ that I want to minimize, then I should find $\nabla_x f$ and update $x$ via gradient descent. However the above implies that $\nabla_x f$ is $n \times m$; how can I use this to update $x$ which is $n \times 1$?

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: In the text it says the matrix 'J' I have in equation (4) would be the jacobian, and that the transpose of the jacobian is the gradient. I ultimately want a gradient, but finding the jacobian should be equivalent...i think

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to understand what $[dg(A^Tx)]d(A^Tx)$ really is. This says that you have a differential of $g$, which is a continuous linear operator of dimensions $m\times m$ (exactly as g), at the point $A^Tx$, it is written as $dg(A^Tx)$. Then you have the input $d(A^Tx)$ (a vector of dimension $m$) to this linear operator $dg(A^Tx)$. As $f$ is a function of $x$ only, you indeed need to treat $A$ as a constant. And then the answer is indeed
$$df=dg(A^Tx)A^Tdx$$
where the dimensions of $dg(A^Tx)$ are $m\times m$, because it is the differential of $g(y)$ at the point $y=A^Tx$ and not the differential of $g(A^Tx)$.

Comment: I am confused by the expression: $df = dg(y) A^T dx $. If $dg(y)$ is $m \times n$ like you say, what operation is in this expression? The differential cant be matrix multiplied with $A^T$ which is also $m \times n$. Also, $g$ was defined as a differentiable function $g:\mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$. So the differential, $dg$, should be $m \times 1$, and the Jacobian matrix should be $m \times m$, right?

Comment: sorry, a mistake, the dimensions of $dg$ are $m\times m$. Edited. The point is that dimensions of $dg$ are the same as for $g$. $dg$ is $m\times m$, $A^Tdx$ is $m\times 1$, so the result of multiplication is $m\times 1$.

Comment: The Jacobian is $dg(y)A^T$ with dimensions $m\times n$.

Answer (score 0):

Why not derive the chain rule yourself?

$$ {\bf f} \left( {\bf x} + {\rm d} {\bf x} \right) = {\bf g} \left( {\bf A}^\top \left( {\bf x} + {\rm d} {\bf x} \right) \right) = {\bf g} \left( {\bf A}^\top {\bf x} + {\bf A}^\top {\rm d} {\bf x} \right) = \underbrace{{\bf g} \left( {\bf A}^\top {\bf x} \right)}_{= {\bf f} \left( {\bf x} \right)} + \color{blue}{{\bf J}_{{\bf g}} \left( {\bf A}^\top {\bf x} \right) {\bf A}^\top} {\rm d} {\bf x} $$

where ${\bf J}_{{\bf g}}$ is the [Jacobian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) of vector field $\bf g$.